# jQuery sortable 'serialize' method returning blank string

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-sortable

My table looks like:

```
<table id="pages_table">
<tr>
 <th>Name</th>
 <th>Sub title</th>
 <th>Icon url</th>
 <th>Order</th>
</tr>

<tbody>
<% @pages.each do |page| %>
<tr id="page<%=page.ordering %>">
  <td><%= page.name %></td>
  <td><%= page.sub_title %></td>
  <td><%= page.icon_url %></td>
  <td><%= page.ordering %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Show', page %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_page_path(page) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', page, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

And my javascript is:

```
$(function() {

 $("#pages_table tbody").sortable({
   update  : function () { 
   var order = $("#pages_table tbody").sortable('serialize'); 
   console.log(order);
  }
 });
});
```

For whatever reason, the console statement prints out a blank string, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Try to add a thead around your table head to ensure thats not the problem, and try to add some extra hard coded test text in the tbody to see if that get selected.

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly the problem! Removing the first set of <tr></tr> tags gets it serialize perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
<tr id="page<%=page.ordering %>">
```

For this one:

```
<tr id="page_<%= page.ordering %>">
```

Looks like `.sortable('serialize')` expects an underscore in id attribute.